# iOS - AVQueuePlayer is not playing the songs and sometimes it is crashing the application When i use mobile data

Tags: ios, avplayer, avqueueplayer

In my Application, playing multiple songs by using AVQueuePlayer through NSURLs. Everything is working fine, when i use wifi to play the songs. If i use mobile data the songs are not playing and some times app is crashing. Please help me out.

Comment: Any logs? and what do you mean by not playing?

Comment: If I enable cellular data, and if click on play button. Song is not playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, the problem is in server side not in code. Uploaded songs are playing by wifi, but  not playing if we use mobile data. This is because of server bandwidth problem. Moved all songs to another server, now songs are playing perfectly by using both wifi and mobile data.